# How to center-align heading and image contained in a div tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have one image and heading tag in a div,
How can I align them like beloved images.

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <img src="http://localhost/chifley-acf/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-01.png" alt="Icon" class="pull-left">
    <h4>Refinancing</h4>
</div>
```

Current output like this

[image]

But I want Like This

[image]

Comment: Add text-align:center to your div

Comment: @Gayathri Mohan  I have tried that, But the image not center with that

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe It might be due to the pull-left class given to your <img>..Can you tell me what is the style given in pull-left class? Can you share a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution for this would be

```css
.wrapper {
text-align: center;
}
.heading, img {
display: inline-block;
}
.heading {
vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix wrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60/0fa" alt="Icon" class="pull-left">
    <h4 class="heading">Refinancing</h4>
</div>
```

Make the display of both the elements in the div inline-block and vertically align the heading text.

Comment: This answer helped me for finding solution, also pull-left removed,
Thanks.

Comment: Can you verify the answer if this helped you? Pleasure to help @ashanrupasinghe

Answer (score 2):

If you assign classes to the element, you can apply the following CSS to them. The essential thing is that the child elements are inline-blocks, which can be centered in their container both horizontally and vertically. Hoizontally they only take as much space as their contents need.

```css
.x {
text-align: center;
}
.y {
display: inline-block;
}
.x img, .y {
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix x">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x60/0fa" alt="Icon" class="pull-left">
    <h4 class="y">Refinancing</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer helped me for finding solution, also pull-left removed,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  <div class="clearfix text-center">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/400/180" alt="Icon" class="pull-left">
<h4>Refinancing</h4>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this work good :

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="block">

          <img src="your_icon.png" class="pull-left">
          <h4>Refinancing</h4>

    </div>
</div>
```

in your CSS file :

```
.clearfix{
/*your code ...*/
position:relative;
}

.block{
display:inline-block;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
transform:TranslateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All,
Find a solution using yours comment and answers,
I removed `pull-left` class and added beloved CSS line

```
       .x {
        text-align: center;
        }
        .y, img {
        display: inline-block;
        }

    <div class="clearfix x">
        <img src="http://localhost/chifley-acf/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/icon-01.png" alt="Icon" class="">
        <h4 class="y">Refinancing</h4>
   </div>
```